# How to access SvelteKit fetch implementation outside the load function

Tags: sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit client that comunicates with backend trought GRAPHQL API interface.
SvelteKit app has only one standalone endpoint that runs the requests trought only one POST Request handler, say /src/routes/endpoint.json.ts

I have a module, say Address.svelte that exposes a smui autocomplete widget to search cities in my country. This component fetches the cities dinamically when a user input on it,  with something like this:

```
   [..] 
   import {findListCity, type ICity } from '$lib/city'
   export let svelteKitFetch
   [...]
   
   async function searchCities(input: string): Promise<ICity[] | false> {
        
            [...]

            return new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => {

                debounceSearchTimer = setTimeout( async () => {
                    try {
                        options = await findCityList({ 
                            fetch: svelteKitFetch, 
                            pagination: { ... },
                            searchOptions: {... } 
                        }); 
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.log("An error occurred ", e);
                        reject(e);
                    }

                    // Return a list of matches.
                    const result ...
                                        
                    resolve(result);

                }, delay || 750 ); 
            });
    }
```

the point of the question I want to highlight is the following:

I have to pass the SvelteKit fetch API wrapper ( **fetch: svelteKitFetch** ) to each component of the hierarchy from a parent component to Address component, to make the call to the endpoint /endpoint.json  inside the component itself. For example from a page like [id].svelte ( trought load function ) to a componente like City.svelte to Address.svelte

Is there a better way to do this, something less cumbersome?
Is there a way to access the fetch wrapper from outside the parent page load function?

Comment: One way to architecture this *might* be to use SvelteKit stores, but this might need some more overall context to understand how do you reuse `Address` and `City`.

Comment: Yes this is a good way.  However I am still wondering if there is a way to directly import the SvelteKit wrapper

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem is that `fetch` is only available run-time, not import time. This is because server-side rendering and frontend have different `fetch` implementations, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Ah ok, for now i get around the problem with $browser env avoiding call the endpoint,  if not in the browser.  Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Page enpoint](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-page-endpoints) is the best way to go for your use case.

If you have an `index.svelte` that query data from `endpoint.json.ts`, rename the `endpoint.json.ts` to `index.ts` so that when you send a `POST` request to your index page, your POST function in `index.ts` will run and pass the data to your Svelte template like this.

#### Index.svelte

```
<script>
    let searchTerms: string = ""

    const searchCities = async ()=>{
        if (searchTerms.length == 0) return

        // because you didn't specify the fetch path,
        // the post request will be sent to the current page
        // which will run your page endpoint post function

        const req = fetch('', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                Accept: 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({searchTerms})
        })
        const results = await req.json()
        // do something with the results
    }
    
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={searchTerms} on:input={searchCities}>
```

#### index.ts

```
export const POST: RequestHandler = async ({ request }) => {
    const { searchTerms } = await request.json()

    // query your database
    const results = []
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: {
            results
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting reply. However, it doesn't seem to be applicable to my case. In fact I have divided the application into modules. For example regarding the city module in /src/lib I have a city directory with /api, /components, /fragments /queries /types . In api I have all the calls that concern this module such as find_cities etc, and each of them takes care of its own settings before and after call to the endpoint. For this reason i have choosen standalone enpoint rather then page endpoint.